# What to use to create a custom grid layout on Zurb Foundation

Tags: layout, grid, zurb-foundation

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to find a solution to creating a responsive custom grid layout on the Zurb Foundation 4 framework.

[Custom Layout](http://imageshack.us/a/img23/6135/vk6s.png)

There will be a set size for bigger blocks and the smaller ones will fill in around it but in this type of pattern as more divs are added.

But in a mobile layout, they will all become the same size and stack.

I've been messing around with mason.js and jQuery masonry but I haven't had any luck. Would either of these work for my problem or is there something else I should look into?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a layout like that with just nested rows and using other grid classes like "small-*", "large-*", push, pull etc

I know you mentioned a JavaScript solution, but I thought I would offer up a crude Html/CSS option.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-5 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-5 columns"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
            <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
            <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
            <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
            <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an extremely rough [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BEH5/2/) example

Obviously some playing around with the column count and possibly customize margins would be in-order. I did remove the media queries since the result window was playing tricks on me.

Hope this helps either way.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin that does just this. check out [www.masonjs.com](http://www.masonjs.com) that should do exactly what you're looking for! Cheers!